# understanding 'native' option for wavread function of Matlab

Tags: matlab

Matlab reads wav files in signed double precision normalized format, which means teh values returned by wavread are between -1 and 1
The wavread function in newer version of Matlab also has an argument called native, which lets us import the raw data in wav file as signed integer numbers
I think it detects the number of bits used to represent one sample in the wav file automatically through the headers of the wav file
What is the relation between the data returned by wavread function with and without the 'native' argument present?
I have tried this:

```
data = wavread('file.wav')  
data_n = wavread('file.wav', 'native')  
data_n(1:10) ./ max( data_n )
```

It shows that the result of this division is almost equal to the values in the variable data, but differ after the 6th or 8th decimal place
Hwo can I make them exactly equal? Or, what is the relationship Matlab uses to convert the native format into default format?

Comment: The `edit` command is always helpful. Type `edit wavread` in the Matlab command window. The code around line 698 looks interesting (Matlab R2012b). Do a find (command- or control-f) to look for other instances of `'native'`.

Comment: Thank you. I think that's it, that's the code that does the conversion.

Comment: The exact code given above gives 0 as the result actually; the numerical values that I described were obtained by looking at the values of the variables data and data_n and performing division on the numbers; why is the code above giving a value of 0?

Comment: I don't have a wave file, but if the `'native'` option returns data as [`uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) integers, then you need to be careful with division between them (and other operations that can easily cause overflow, underflow, or unwanted rounding) as the output will also be `uint8`. This is one of the reasons for working with doubles in Matlab's default format.

Comment: it returns in the "Samples in the native data type found in the file."; it probably detects this from the wav file header and in my case it returns int16. So is there any way I can perform a type cast to double like in C?

Comment: Use the [`double`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/double.html) function.